# iCarousel app throws Thread1: signal SIGBRT

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icarousel

What am I doing wrong??
I always get the Thread1: signal SIGBRT error....
I connected a UIView (changed it to iCarousel with file owner) to object called icrousel from type iCarousel, and its delegates. When I disconnect it from all the above the app running (without its real functionality).

h file:

```
///
///
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iCarousel.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDelegate,iCarouselDataSource>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel *icarousel;

    @end
```

m file:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  CarouselTry
//
//  Created by Assaf Grimberg on 5/2/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Assaf Grimberg. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize icarousel;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

-(void)carouselDidScroll:(iCarousel *)carousel{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Carousel Scroll" message:@"YEH" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];    
}

-(void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Item selected" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 6;
}



- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 180)];
    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", @"gift", index, @".png"];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [view addSubview:imageView];

    return view;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //note: placeholder views are only displayed on some carousels if wrapping is disabled
    return 0;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 180)];
    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", @"gift", index, @".png"];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [view addSubview:imageView];

    return view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    icarousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 180)];
    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", @"gift", index, @".png"];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [view addSubview:imageView];

    return view;
}
```

your code may be like this

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)view;

    if ( !imgView )
    {
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 180)];
    }

    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"gift%d.png",index]];

    return imgView;
}
```

Comment: I get the error in appdelegate when calling MakeKeyAndVisible

Comment: What should be the control of icarousel? Should I drag UIView and change it to icarousel?

Comment: Yes, use a UIView as the base class I interface builder.